# How to implement saving of lists (adding/removing/saving items) using Angular and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework-4

I have an application where a list of objects is to be managed in a web view.

When a user loads the page, an AJAX request is made to an ASP MVC controller, which in turn calls Entity Framework to fetch the list of objects from a SQL server. The controller formats the list as JSON and sends it back to the client where it is bound to a view using Angular.

The user is then able to make changes to the list in the view. Once they are finished, they hit a save button which sends the modified list back to ASP MVC.

My question is: What is the best way to save these changes back to SQL server? Should I do something extra on the frontend, or can I do it all on the backend?

Comment: What are you proposing to *do* on the front end?

Comment: The front end allows landlords to build application forms in a web view. They can add/remove fields that will be present in the form (this is the list I'm talking about.)

Comment: I mean with regards to saving changes in a database.

Comment: The application forms they build will be attached to their account for later printing/editing.

Comment: What I'm asking is what is the "something extra on the front end" you're proposing. Your question is unclear as it's written - there's no obvious tie to a database from your web page *without* "the back end".

Comment: Ah ok, what I mean by "something extra" would be marking items as deleted with a flag on each object in the list. That way when I send the list to the backend I can delete objects marked for deletion etc.

The thing is I'd prefer to find a way to save changes on the backend without having to tie the front/backend implementations together with a flagging mechanism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71731/discussion-between-cameron-wilby-and-preston-guillot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how I'm going to do this.

1. Create a temporary list containing items in the database that are not present in the list returned by the view.
2. Reverse loop through the temporary list and remove each item from the database.